# question tags for sentences with dummy elements

Tags: grammar, questions

I have a question about question tags.

> That is our new teacher, isn't it?

or

> That is our new teacher, isn't he?

Which one is correct?

Comment: I'd refer back to the dummy element _That_ rather than the delayed subject _our new teacher_. So I'd use 'it' here. //  The French are almost always happy with 'isn't it?' ('nest-ce pas?'), and there's a move to do the same in English, but I wouldn't use 'He's our new teacher, isn't it?' quite yet. And 'He's our new teacher, innit?' will take rather longer for me to accept as standard.

Comment: In actuality, “That’s our new teacher, ***right***?”  avoids all the awkwardness.  Which is of course short for “Isn’t that right”

Comment: It would be more articulate to say, "Isn't he our new teacher?" or "Is that our new teacher?"

Answer (score 1):

I think that 'it' is not referring to the teacher.

'That is the new teacher, is it not (true) ?'

'That is the new teacher, is it not (a fact) ?'

'That is the new teacher, is it not (the case) ?

I  believe it is quite correct to say 'it' because the 'it' is not a person but refers back to the *fact* that 'that is the teacher'.

Answer (score 0):

My take here is that this is a case of IDENTIFYING a person, in which case it's standard to use third person gender neutral forms, so "isn't it?" is right. The dummy element you mentioned Edwin is not relevant imho.

Identifying
- Looking at a photo of a crowd: "THAT's John, isn't IT?""
- On the phone: "Is THAT Sue?" "Yes. THAT's Lisa, isn't IT?""
 - In the scenario described and other similar situations: "Evening everyone, great party! THIS is my friend Maria."

An exception is introducing OURSELVES face to face when we say: "Hi, I'm Mark. Are you Dave?". Or "You're Dave, aren't you?"

Comment: "Is he the one who punched you?" would not work with **it**, even though it's also a case of identifying a person. Similarly, "who punched you" is correct, but "what punched you?" is not (when referring to a person). You're getting confused with the gender neutral "they" (which is contested by some grammarians, last I heard).

Comment: "Is that the boy who punched you?" "Yes, it is" - also extremely common of not more so.

Comment: @Flater: You'd say: *"Who's on the phone?" "It's our new teacher."* And not *"Who's on the phone?" "He's our new teacher."* So *it* is perfectly correct here. You're right ... not all cases of identification take *it*. But this one does.

Comment: I noticed that we do this - switching to it / this / that for identifying - learning another language where they don't. But clearly there are exceptions, elastic 'rules'.

Comment: @MarkEK: All examples you use in the comments use "it" in **the answer**, not in **the question**. The current topic is about the usage of "it" in a question, not in an answer. "Is **it** calling you?" is in no way correct, but "Are **they** calling you?" is correct.

Comment: @Flater - that is exactly how the original query is presented: "That is our new teacher, isn't it?" v "..., isn't he?" I agree of course the "It is .." creation you posited is not correct. We use "This/that" to identify and "it" in tags and answers.

Answer (score 0):

### It/he should (usually) match the main subject.

> **That** is our new teacher, isn't **he**?

Is incorrect. It should be:

> **He** is our new teacher, isn't **he**?
>   **That man** is our new teacher, isn't **he**?

The (second) "he" refers to the subject ("he"/"that man").

---

> **That** is our new teacher, isn't **it**?

This is correct, since "it" refers to "that".

---

### There is an exception to this.

> **He** is our new teacher, isn't **it**?

"isn't it?" is also considered correct, especially in UK English (where it often gets shortened to "innit?"). I'm doubtful whether this is considered correct in US English. I suspect that it isn't.

Essentially, "it" is not referring to "he", it is referring to **the assumption** (which the question is trying to confirm).

This becomes easier to understand if we use a plural subject:

> The students are all going to graduate, aren't they?

"They" refers to "the students".

> The students are all going to graduate, isn't it?

Note that "the students" is plural, but "it" is singular. "It" cannot possibly be referring to "the students".

"It" refers to the assumption (that all students are going to graduate). It's essentially the same as:

> [I assume that] The students are all going to graduate. Is **this assumption** correct?

---

*Note that I refer to an **assumption**, but I could've referred to it as an expectation, inference, understanding, ... the exact word to use here isn't relevant, it depends on the context. The important part is that the assumption/expectation/inference/... **is not a person**.*

Comment: But in answer to *"who's at the door"*, you'd say "*it's the mailman"* and not *"he's the mailman."* The use of *it* for identification is much broader than just confirming the assumption of the speaker. (And using *isn't it* as a general question tag is a very British thing to do. Americans wouldn't say *He's our new teacher, innit*. I don't really know whether people would say it in the U.K., either, but my impression is that they might.)

Comment: @PeterShor: You're using "it" in the answer, not in the question. That changes things.

Comment: No it doesn't. Suppose you hear somebody outside your door making noise. Wouldn't you ask *"that's the mailman, isn't it?"*

Comment: @PeterShor: Yes, but how does that invalidate my answer? I agreed that "isn't it?" is correct to use, but "it" simply doesn't refer to "the mailman". In essence, you're not asking "is [the mailman correct]?", you're asking "is [**my assumption** correct]?"

Comment: No. You're asking: is the cause of the noise the mailman? You wouldn't say *"They shoot horses, isn't it?"* Even though in that question, you're ***also*** asking whether your assumption is correct.

Comment: "..., isn't he?" - no, I disagree. Not correct. Discussed above; phone English is best example.

Comment: @PeterShor: In which case "it" refers to "that", which refers to "the cause of the noise". As in: _"I heard **a noise**. **That** is the mailman, isn't **it**?"_

Comment: @Flater: That's my point. In *That's our new teacher, isn't it?* the word *it* can stand for many things. But in American English, it can't stand for "the assumption of the speaker."

Comment: @MarkEK: Upon rereading, I agree that "Isn't he?" doesn't work here. Updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: Another good eg besides phone English - a group-photo.

Comment: @MarkEK: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: BRE 'Innit?' means "isn't it true?"  ("isn't it so?", etc.)  AME would use 'true?' which seems like a wiser use of elision.

Comment: @Ami: American English would be much more likely to use *"right?"*.

Comment: You are *"Correct!"*

Comment: "The students are all going to graduate, isn't it" sounds completely errant to me, in AmE. We'd have to re-translate the "isn't it?/innit?" BrE expression into its relative AmE form, which'd be something like "right?" to do the job.

Comment: “He’s our new teacher, isn’t it?” is absolutely not correct or used in any form of British English I’ve ever encountered. When _isn’t it_ is used as a genericised negative tag question, it is **mandatorily** contracted to _innit_ in BrE. The only place I’ve heard it used uncontracted is in Singlish, and I’m not even sure it’s common there.